# Pass value from clickable table row into Python using Flask/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

So, I am new to Python and Flask, and building an aplication which shows a list of portfolios in a table. Now, I made these rows clickable using js/Jquery. What I would like to acchieve however, is that the value of the second column of the clicked row (portfolio_id) is somehow returned to Python. The idea is that after selecting a portfolio from the list, a new screen with the details of that specific portfolio appears, so Python needs to know which portfolio to load. I do manage to include a href/link into the click event, so the new screen appears, but I cant figure out how to get the value from my table into my Python code.... Below the Flask code:

```html
{% block main %}
<h2>Portfolio List</h2>
 <ul>
     <table style="width:100%">
     <tr> 
         <th>Relationship Nbr </th>
         <th>Portfolio Nbr </th>
         <th>Strategy </th>
         <th>Portfolios </th>
         <th>Last Rebalancing </th>
     </tr>
    {% for portfolio in portfolios %}
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href="{{ url_for('portfolio') }}" method = POST> 
         <td>{{portfolio.rel_nbr }} </td>
         <td>{{portfolio.portfolio_id}}</td>
         <td>{{portfolio.strategy_name}} </td>
         <td>{{portfolio.security_list}} </td>
         <td>{{portfolio.last_rebalance}} </td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

The jquery code I use is as follows:

```js
    src="jquery-3.2.1.min-js">
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

Any ideas how this can be done?
Txs!!
Bart

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me. I have just changed place for jquery script.

Try to place your jquery script in proper place. I think this is the only reason your code is not working.

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
       alert($(this).data("href"));
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

```html
{% block main %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Portfolio List</h2>
 <ul>
     <table style="width:100%">
     <tr> 
         <th>Relationship Nbr </th>
         <th>Portfolio Nbr </th>
         <th>Strategy </th>
         <th>Portfolios </th>
         <th>Last Rebalancing </th>
     </tr>
    {% for portfolio in portfolios %}
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href="{{ url_for('portfolio') }}" method = POST> 
         <td>{{portfolio.rel_nbr }} </td>
         <td>{{portfolio.portfolio_id}}</td>
         <td>{{portfolio.strategy_name}} </td>
         <td>{{portfolio.security_list}} </td>
         <td>{{portfolio.last_rebalance}} </td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Well, the code is working for me as well; just that I do not know how to pass the value of "portfolio_id" (i.e. a cell in the clicked row) back into my Python code.....

Comment: you can pass the value of "portfolio_id" in another attribute field like data-attr-id="ID" in tr tag and on click you can get from jquery and concate with your href link.

Comment: Right, so I need to amend my jquery to something like this?
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
        var portfolio_id = $(this).data("portfolio-id");
    });
});
And the Flask/html into:
<tr class='clickable-row' data-href="{{ url_for('portfolio') }}" data-portfolo-id="{{portfolio.portfolio_id}}" method = POST> 
How do I then get the value from jQeary into Python, so I know which portfolio I should load in the next screen?